# TF400324: Azure DevOps services are not available from server - Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I got Visual Studio 2019 and I haven't done any updates recently.
This is the error I got when trying to connect to TFS:

```
TF400324: Azure DevOps services are not available from server xxxx.
Technical information (for administrator):
  The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
```

I tried closing all visual studio instances and cleaning the cache and it didn't work. Also tried to use to http and https, neither worked as well.
Anyone knows what is wrong with Visual Studio 2019 and how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: If you are using `https` in server address change it to `http` and check once.

Comment: It didn't work for me

Comment: Have you contacted your TFS administrator to see if there's an issue with the server? That's the most likely culprit.

Comment: You are trying to connect TFS, but the issue looks like the VS is trying to connect Azure DevOps services.

Comment: What about reset the userdata: cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE
devenv.exe /resetuserdata